# How to replace data in html form with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML form with three fields. Field A for input text, and fields B and C for number input.

I created a function to calculate B i C, and to output data from A,B and C onto the page.

How can I make it so that field A must be filled in, and fields B and C must be a positive value?

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tax calculator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Field A:<input id="name" type="text">
        Field B:<input id="tBas" type="value">
        Field C:<input id="tRat" type="value">
        <button id="calc">Calculate !</button>
    </div>
    <strong>
        <div id="name"> </div>
        <div id="income"> </div>
        <div id="rate"> </div>
        <div id="result"> </div>
    </strong>
    <script src="testCalculate.js">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```js
function calculate() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var base = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tBas').value);
    var rate = document.getElementById('tRat').value;

    var taxPayer = ("First and last name: ") + (name);
    var taxIncome = ("Income for taxation: ") + ((base).toFixed(2));
    var taxRate = ("Tax rate: ") + (rate) + ("%.");
    var taxToPay = ("You need to pay: ") + ((base * rate / 100).toFixed(2));

    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = taxPayer;
    document.getElementById('income').innerHTML = taxIncome;
    document.getElementById('rate').innerHTML = taxRate;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = taxToPay;
}

document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

Comment: For field B and C `type="value"` to  `type="number" min=0` ; Use required for field A

Comment: _"How to apply in JS..."_ - Why JavaScript? Those input elements should be in a form and then just use the built-in form validation.

Comment: Because I attend course and haven't yet passed unit consider built-in form validation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if a field is filled, you can just compare his value to `""`.

To check if a field has a positive value, you can use `parseInt` to cast your value (which is a string) into an integer and then compare it to 0 `> 0`.

Something like that should do the trick !

```js
function calculate() {    
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var base = parseFloat(document.getElementById('tBas').value);
  var rate = document.getElementById('tRat').value;
  
  if (name != "" && parseInt(base) > 0 && parseInt(rate) > 0) {
    var taxPayer = ("First and last name: ")+(name); 
    var taxIncome = ("Income for taxation: ")+((base).toFixed(2)); 
    var taxRate = ("Tax rate: ")+(rate)+("%."); 
    var taxToPay = ("You need to pay: ")+((base*rate/100).toFixed(2));

    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = taxPayer;
    document.getElementById('income').innerHTML = taxIncome;    
    document.getElementById('rate').innerHTML = taxRate;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = taxToPay;
  }
}

document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', calculate);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Tax calculator</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">          
    </head>
    <body> 
      <div>
          Field A:<input id="name" type="text">
          Field B:<input id="tBas" type="value">
          Field C:<input id="tRat" type="value">
          <button id="calc">Calculate !</button>      
      </div>
      <strong>
      <div id="name"> </div>
      <div id="income"> </div>
      <div id="rate"> </div>
      <div id="result"> </div>    
      </strong>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you ! After your help I added this:else { 
alert("Must fill First and last name !!! Must fill positive value for income !!!"); 
   }

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JS for this trick
To have the input filled set it as

```
<input id="name" type="text" required>
```

Then to have an positive value

```
<input id="tBas" type="number" min=0 >
```

Answer (score 0):

IDs should be uniq. You should use another id to you `div#name`.

For instance, into your html code:

```
 <div id="div_name"> </div>
```

And then, into your script

```
document.getElementById('div_name').innerHTML= taxPayer;
```